# Merge two rows in a same table after calculating average values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in my table named **prices** as below;

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
| ID                                   | E5    | E10   | DIESEL | DATE       |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
| a1978958-a6c4-447b-a90c-3d189da0f831 | 1.289 | 1.269 |  1.059 | 07/22/2017 |
| a1978958-a6c4-447b-a90c-3d189da0f831 | 1.259 | 1.239 |  1.029 | 07/22/2017 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
```

I want to calculate average values of E5, E10, DIESEL. Then I want to merge two columns with ID and DATE inside same table. (Column name and order will  remain same)

```
select ID, DATE, avg(E5) as E5, avg(E10) as E10, avg(DIESEL) as DIESEL from prices group by ID, DATE;
```

Then I inserted the following query.

```
select t1.ID, t2.ID, t1.DATE, t2.DATE from prices as t1 inner join prices as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.DATE = t2.DATE;
```

I couldn't achieve merging two rows with two above-mentioned queries. Result will be the following figure in all row values.

```
  +--------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
    | ID                                   | E5    | E10   | DIESEL | DATE       |
    +--------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
    | a1978958-a6c4-447b-a90c-3d189da0f831 | 1.274 | 1.254 |  1.044 | 07/22/2017 |
    +--------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
```

Is there any idea how to do?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your first query is what I would have given as an answer, but apparently you have something else in mind.  Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: When I entered the first query, I will get the proper result. But I want to save this value into my table so that I will not have values in the above figure. For example I have  a1978958-a6c4-447b-a90c-3d189da0f831 id value and it has multiple rows with same date. I want to save this into table as a unique row

Comment: What happens to the original two records?  Could you put the result you want into a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking for:

```
select ID, avg(E5) as E5, avg(E10) as E10, avg(DIESEL) as DIESEL
from prices
group by ID;
```

Does this do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

is this the thing that you are looking for: kept the result on temp table, deleted the actual values, and inserted the avg values to the same table?

```
SELECT ID, avg(E5) as E5, avg(E10) as E10, avg(DIESEL) as DIESEL, DATE INTO #TEMP from prices group by ID, DATE
DELETE FROM prices
INSERT INTO prices SELECT * FROM #TEMP
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: When I entered the first query, I will get the proper result. But I want to save this value into my table so that I will not have values in the above figure. For example, I have a1978958-a6c4-447b-a90c-3d189da0f831 id value and it has multiple rows with the same date. I want to save this into table as a unique row